# C, 2D Array, How to find specific number in all 8 directions

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, 2d

You are allowed to enter only 0 and 1 as values in the arrays. Then in place of all elements having a value of 0, enter the number of elements with a value of 1 around that element in all eight directions. And on the end print the 2d array and the values with 1 change to *.

Here is an example how it's supposed to look like:

[image]

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int n,m;
scanf("%d%d", &n, &m);
int a[n][m];
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<m; j++){
        scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        if(a[i][j]==1){
            a[i][j]=9;
        }
    }
}
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<m; j++){
        int counter=0;
        if(a[i][j]==9){
            printf("*\t");
        }else if(a[i][j]==0){
        if(a[i+1][j+1]==9 && i!=n && j!=m) counter++;
        if(a[i-1][j-1]==9 && i!=0 && j!=0) counter++;
        if(a[i+1][j-1]==9 && i!=n && j!=0) counter++;
        if(a[i-1][j+1]==9 && i!=0 && j!=m) counter++;
        if(a[i][j+1]==9 && j!=m) counter++;
        if(a[i][j-1]==9 && j!=0) counter++;
        if(a[i+1][j]==9 && i!=n) counter++;
        if(a[i-1][j]==9 && i!=0) counter++;
        a[i][j]=counter;
        counter=0;
        printf("%d\t", a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
 }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @d3ko What is this statement if(a[i][j]==1){
            a[i][j]=9;
        } doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have UB (undefined behavior).

With (e.g.):

```
if (a[i + 1][j + 1] == 9 && i != n && j != m)
```

Then, `a` is *always* fetched, even if `i` or `j` is out of range.

To fix this, reorder the terms:

```
if (i != n && j != m && a[i + 1][j + 1] == 9)
```

Now, if either `i` or `j` is out of range, then the `if` will be "short circuited": (i.e. _short circuit evaluation) and the `a` value will *not* be fetched.

But, your program output is incorrect. You're coding everything out longhand. It makes it hard to debug (i.e. which lines have a bug).

What wasn't explicitly described was that you are summing the non-zero values in a 3x3 kernal around a given zero point.

The hardcoding doesn't *scale* too well. Suppose the kernal had to be 100x100. Would we code up 10,000 lines of code?

---

It's much easier to debug if we refactor to use `for` loops. And, to use more descriptive names instead of `i/j/m/n`:

```
n       hgt
m       wid
i       y*
j       x*
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int hgt, wid;
    int counter;
    FILE *xf;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    if (argc > 0)
        xf = fopen(*argv,"r");
    else
        xf = stdin;
    if (xf == NULL) {
        perror(*argv);
        exit(1);
    }

    fscanf(xf,"%d%d", &hgt, &wid);
    int a[hgt][wid];

    for (int ycur = 0; ycur < hgt; ycur++) {
        for (int xcur = 0; xcur < wid; xcur++) {
            int val;
            fscanf(xf,"%d", &val);

            if (val == 1)
                val = 9;

            a[ycur][xcur] = val;
        }
    }

    for (int yctr = 0; yctr < hgt; yctr++) {
        for (int xctr = 0; xctr < wid; xctr++) {
            if (a[yctr][xctr] == 9) {
                printf("*\t");
                continue;
            }

            counter = 0;
            for (int yoff = -1; yoff <= 1; yoff++) {
                int ycur = yctr + yoff;

                if (ycur < 0)
                    continue;
                if (ycur >= hgt)
                    continue;

                for (int xoff = -1; xoff <= 1; xoff++) {
                    int xcur = xctr + xoff;

                    if (xcur < 0)
                        continue;
                    if (xcur >= wid)
                        continue;

                    counter += (a[ycur][xcur] == 9);
                }
            }

            printf("%d\t",counter);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here  is the program output for your sample input:

```
*   1   1   2   *
2   2   2   *   3
*   1   2   *   2
```

Comment: Fixed my bug thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the question is, but there are bugs in the code -
you are accessing out of array boundaries by doing, for example, this:

```
if(a[i-1][j-1]==9 && i!=0 && j!=0)
```

When i and j are zeros you are reading the value of a[-1][-1]. Changing the order of conditions and checking i and j first would guard against such an access.
Same happens when you access the "borders" of the matrix.
And, the "i!=n && j!=m" condition is always true within the loops - you iterate as long as i<n and j<m.

But aside of that, some of these accesses in fact read from **within** the array, but from a wrong location.
Here is an example that shows that:

Given the matrix of 2x2

```
0 1
1 0
```

This is the result your code produced:

```
2   *
*   3
```

Where obviously, '3' is wrong.

Why it happened?
The 2D array is in fact stored as a 1D array in memory, like this:

```
0  1  1  0  // this is your data

0  1  2  3  // this is the index in the array (offset from the array start)
```

And each element is located at an offset of row*columns+column from the array start (i.e. this is the formula to find the index in 1D array given i and j).
When you count the '1'-neighbours for the last element (a[1][1] in this example), you count the two obvious results (at a[1][0] and a[0][1]), but then you hit this condition:

```
if(a[i-1][j+1]==9 && i!=0 && j!=m)
```

For this last cell, i is 1 and j is 1, so the second part of the condition is true.
But what about a[i-1][j+1]==9 ?
This references a memory at row*columns+column, right? I.e. (i-1)*2+(j+1), because that's what you tried to access. Substituting i and j with 1 and 1, and you get offset 2 in the 1D array above.
Which is 1 in the input matrix (or actually 9 since you've replaced it).
So you count it twice.

Guarding better against "stepping out" of the matrix (but not necessarily out of the actual array) will solve this bug.